# Force.com IDE Unable to do save to server with and Eclipse (windows 10)

Tags: force.com, ide, eclipse

I installed the latest recommended version of Eclipse & the force.com IDE plugin , as described in the instructions (I installed version starting with **"34."**): https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_IDE_Installation

Then I created a force.com project for a sandbox environment , provided the user id , password and token, which downloaded the project contents from the server into eclipse.

But now if I make change to any class and try to save , I get the error

> "Unable to connect to organization with given login credentials" .

So I tried to use the option "Deploy to server" and that works fine with the same username password and token. Dont know why.

I have selected the "Work Online" option. Also , if I try to do a "refresh from server" for the project, I get the same error so I tried to update the project properties. But when I fill in the username + password + token, and click on "Apply", it tries to re-fetch the project components, but gets stuck for some read only component, so there is a dialog box that asks if I want to skip all read-only warnings and if I say yes, it does nothing, the project doesn't get refreshed and I am stuck. If I click no, there are so many more read-only warning dialog boxes that follow, that I gave up.

I have no idea how to get around this issue, I tried installing older versions of eclipse, kepler , which I was using on my old laptop and was working fine, also juno, neon ,and that doesnt work, neither does installing any other version of the force.com IDE. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. At least in my case, if I use the 32-bit eclipse, force.com IDE works with it, but not if I use the 64-bit eclipse(even though my OS is 64-bit).

Comment: I am not sure why it is not working for you. But for a side note I am using windows 10 64 bit and using eclipse(kepler version) without any issue. Not sure about your issue.